# Dagger 2 issue with sub-component and a component with a dependency component

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm working on Dagger 2 and met with a dependency injection issue. I'll give you an idea into the problem. I've an ApplicationComponent as shown below.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, MySubComponent.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
   void inject(Application app);
   List<Integer> pattern;
   MySubComponent subcomponent();
}
```

As you can see, I've a sub-component defined in the above component.

```
ApplicationComponent comp = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new ApplicationModule())
                .mySubModule(new MySubModule())
                .build();
```

This is how I created application component instance.

Here's the sub-component

```
@Singleton
@Subcomponent(modules = MySubModule.class)
public interface MySubComponent {
   void inject(AClass obj);

   INeedThis ineedthis(); 
}

@Module
public class MySubComponent {
   @Provides
   @Singleton
   INeedThis provideINeedThis() {
      return new INeedThis();
   }
}
```

I then created another component, LoginComponent with ApplicationComponent as a dependency

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity{}

@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent {
    void inject(FirstActivity activity);
}
```

I created LoginComponent instance as below.

```
LoginComponent comp = DaggerLoginComponent.builder().loginModule(new LoginModule().applicationComponent(appComponentObject).build();
```

The issue happens when I inject INeedThis object in FirstActivity. My assumption is since LoginComponent has a dependency of ApplicationComponent which has a sub-component MySubComponent, INeedThis object should be injected. But in reality, it fails to do so and I get the following error.

```
INeedThis cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces- annotated methods.
```

I read many posts on sub-components on dagger 2. However, they didn't work as expected. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you are not using subcomponents in the code above and this issue is not related to them, but that is another issue.

Your `LoginComponent` *depends* on `ApplicationComponent` as declared with this:

```
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent {}
```

What this means is that using your `LoginComponent` you can inject everything that the `LoginComponent` knows about. That is everything provided from `LoginModule`, possible objects that can be created by constructor injection *and **exposed** objects from your `ApplicationComponent`.

> INeedThis cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces- annotated methods.

This says, that for `INeedThis` none of those is true.

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, MySubComponent.class})
```

I don't know how/why you add a *component* as a *module*. If this is a typo, and you add `MySubModule` to your component you would just have to add the following to *expose* `INeedThis`:

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, MySubModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    //...
    INeedThis getINeedThis();
}
```

---

If this is not a typo and you actually want to use a subcomponent, then your `LoginComponent` should depend on the actual subcomponent, but it would work the same way once you fix your code to actually use sub components.

Given your subcomponent definition above, you'd change your app component to not list the component as a module, and add a method to *extend* your `ApplicationComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class}) // removed from modules
public interface ApplicationComponent {
   void inject(Application app);
   List<Integer> pattern;
   MySubComponent subcomponent(); // this will create your subcomponent

   // same as above
   // MySubComponent subcomponent(MySubModule module); use this if you also need to setup your module
}
```

Then you'd create your subcomponent like the following:

```
AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppcomponent.create();
MySubComponent subComponent = appComponent.subcomponent(); // call the method  on your app component
```

Then if you change your `LoginComponent` like the following:

```
@Component(dependencies = MySubComponent.class, modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent { /**/ }
```

You can then create it like

```
DaggerLoginComponent.builder().loginModule(new LoginModule().mySubComponent(subComponent).build();
```

And the same as above, you will have to add a `getINeedThis()` to your `MySubComponent` interface to *expose* the object to the sub graph.

Comment: The idea of setting up sub-component is hard to understand. Can you please brief me how to set a sub-component? Basically, I need an ApplicationComponent with a sub-component. All other components with ApplicationComponent as a dependency should have access to sub-component. Correct me if this is not the norm!

Comment: @Renjith please bear in mind that this site is for specific programming questions and not general coding information. How or why you need to use a sub component depends on what you are trying to accomplish and I can not answer this for you. I have updated the answer, if you still need more information you should look for some actual tutorials and try a bit yourself

Comment: Thanks for your edited answer! I did try to incorporate it in my app, but it didn't work. Perhaps, what I'm aiming to accomplish might be slightly different. However, I digged deep into some of the github samples and made it to work.